# Search Shapefile and return Extents

Tags: pyqgis

Looking to convert this Arcpy script to pyQGIS. I sure Hope pyGIS has an user input that works outside the command line.

```
# make custom button to search Parcels by Parcel Number
# and zoom to selected parcel
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers") [0]
input_PIN = raw_input('Enter your value :')
sql_exp = """"PIN" = '""" + input_PIN + "'"
Llayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\common\Gene\Parcels.shp")
Llayer.definitionQuery = sql_exp
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, Llayer)
dfNEWextent = Llayer.getExtent()
df.extent = dfNEWextent
```

---

```
PYQGIS Code:

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QInputDialog
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\Program Files\QGIS Pisa\bin", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
cLayer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
input_PIN = QInputDialog.getText(None,'Parcel Number','Enter PIN:')
expr = QgsExpression(""""PIN" = '""" + input_PIN + "'")
it = cLayer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) 
ids = [i.id() for i in it]
cLayer.setSelectedFeatures( ids )
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

Comment: QgsMapLayer has an extent property as QgsRectange, you should only need to open as QgsVectorLayer with the constructor then the extent should be accessible.. do you have PyQgis code yet? That would be more helpful in this case than arcpy code.

Comment: What happens when you run your code?